# Format string not a literal warning

Tags: nsstring

I have a call to the method

```
 [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:string1 defaultButton:@"OK" alternateButton:@"" otherButton:@"" informativeTextWithFormat:infoString]
```

I need my infoString to be a string variable and that's how I have it set up. However, I am getting a warning saying "Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)."

I tried googling to find an answer, but none of the suggestions I found worked in my case. I tried replacing infoString with:

```
 [NSString stringWithString:infoString];
```

and

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", infoString];
```

I can't find a way to get rid of this warning. Any suggestions are welcome and helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Embrace the warning message.

Answer (score 2):

The `informativeTextWithFormat` is expecting a format string, which should be a constant for security reasons.

For a simple fix, change to this:

```
[NSAlert alertWithMessageText:string1
                defaultButton:@"OK"
              alternateButton:@""
                  otherButton:@""
    informativeTextWithFormat:@"%@", infoString];
```

Comment: I had to read that about three times before I saw the new `@"%@"`, at which point I understood what was going on. Obscure or what?!